# Android "plus 1" button

Tags: android, button

I am starting on an Android app but I need some help.

I have a Textview and two buttons +1 and -1. When you press +1 there should be `1` in my textview and inversely with the -1 button. I can't find my mistake.
Here is my code.

Activity.java

```
package tbj.android.basketballstatistik;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView toPtGoalField;
    Button plus;
    Button minus;
    String oper = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
            plus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
            minus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);

            plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    minusinus.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
    float textview= 0;



    textview= Float.parseFloat(this.textview.getText().toString());



    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.plus:

      oper = "+";
      textview= 1+textview;
      textview.setText(1+ textview); 


      break;
    case R.id.minus:
      oper = "-";
      textview= textview- 1;
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }



    }
}
```

**Edit**
Got it to work with yours help with this code

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.plus:
          if (count == 0 || count == -1) {
              count++;
              textview.setText("" + count);
          }
          break;
      case R.id.minus:
          if (count == 0 || count == 1) {                  
              count--;
              textview.setText("" + count); 
          }
          break;
      default:
          break;
   }

}
```

}

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting if any, and what is displaying in the TextView instead of 1 or -1? Also, what have you tried so far to fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

See if the following code fixes your problem:

```
package tbj.android.basketballstatistik;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView toPtGoalField;
Button plus;
Button minus;
String oper = "";
int counter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        plus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);

        textview.setText("0");
        count = 0;

        plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        minusinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.plus:
              if (count == 0 || count == -1) {
                  count++;
                  textview.setText("" + count);
              }
              break;
          case R.id.minus:
              if (count == 0 || count == 1) {                  
                  count--;
                  textview.setText("" + count); 
              }
              break;
          default:
              break;
       }

    }

}
```

The code above changes the state of the textview in increments. For example, if the current state is `1`, then a click on `minus` will set the textview value to `0`. Another click on `minus` will set its value to `-1`. Subsequent clicks on `minus` will be ignored. If you would like the textbox to show `1` when `plus` is pressed, and `-1` when `minus` is pressed, replace the switch statement to:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.plus:   

              textview.setText("1");  

              break;
          case R.id.minus:

              textview.setText("-1"); 

              break;
          default:
              break;
       }
```

In this case, get rid of the `count` variable as it serves no purpose.

Comment: @Thor1401 Can you give an example of what you mean by divide?

Comment: yes.
Fx istead of plus the textView with 1. then divide with 2.
PS. Thank for the quick answer

Comment: @Thor1401 So, if the `TextView` is currently showing `1`, and you press a `Button`, it should show `0.5`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: no. Fx if the textview is showing fx 4 And I press a button and the button divide 4 with fx 2 and then the textview is showing 2. Can this code work with my example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i think vikram code works the problem with your code is once u have incremented your are setting to textview which is declared locally u are not referring to textview which u have created in onCreate();